# Call a function with its parameters if all required keys are pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that will call another function (passed as a parameter) if all the required keys are pressed. This is what I have so far:

```
function multiKeyPress(funcName, parms, key0, key1, key2, key3, key4, key5) {
  var down = [];
  var noKeys = arguments.length - 2
  var args = parms

  // for (i = 0; i < noKeys; i++) {
  //   if (i == noKeys - 1) {
  //     keyPress += ('down[key' + i + '])')
  //   } else {
  //     keyPress += ('down[key' + i + '] && ')
  //   }
  // }

  console.log(noKeys)
  console.log(args);

  switch (noKeys) {
    case 1:
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        down[e.keyCode] = true;
      }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (down[key0]) {
          funcName.apply(this, args);
        }
        down[e.keyCode] = false;
      });
    break;

    case 2:
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        down[e.keyCode] = true;
      }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (down[key0] && down[key1]) {
          funcName.apply(this, args);
        }
        down[e.keyCode] = false;
      });
    break;

    case 3:
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        down[e.keyCode] = true;
      }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (down[key0] && down[key1] && down[key2]) {
          funcName.apply(this, args);
        }
        down[e.keyCode] = false;
      });
    break;

    case 4:
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        down[e.keyCode] = true;
      }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (down[key0] && down[key1] && down[key2] && down[key3]) {
          funcName.apply(this, args);
        }
        down[e.keyCode] = false;
      });
    break;

    case 5:
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        down[e.keyCode] = true;
      }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (down[key0] && down[key1] && down[key2] && down[key3] && down[key4]) {
          funcName.apply(this, args);
        }
        down[e.keyCode] = false;
      });
    break;

    case 6:
      $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        down[e.keyCode] = true;
      }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (down[key0] && down[key1] && down[key2] && down[key3] && down[key4] && down[key5]) {
          funcName.apply(this, args);
        }
        down[e.keyCode] = false;
      });
    break;
  }
}
```

Near the top of the function I have commented out a loop that would create a string with the necessary keys but I couldnt pass that as a condition because a string will be a truthy value. Therefore I resorted to a long switch statement. This currently works but I was wondering if there was a way to clean it up or if there are any potential problems.

Thanks

Comment: If you're open to using a library, I would look at https://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: a string would _not_ be a truthy value -- if you only create it when a key exists

Comment: @WhiteHat that is true but how would that help me avoid a long switch statement unless I statically define the keys. I need a way of knowing if the keys (passed as parameters) are pressed.

Comment: @J4G I am trying to avoid a library but I appreciate the link. That would definitely solve all my needs

Comment: _"This currently works but I was wondering if there was a way to clean it up or if there are any potential problems."_ Isn't this question for Code Review?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis First time asking a question on here. I'll post this type question in code review next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to think about using arrays.

```
function multiKeyPress(funcName, parms) {
  var keysPressed = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  var down = [];
  $(window).keydown(function(e) {
    down[e.keyCode] = true;
  }).keyup(function(e) {
    var allPressed = keysPressed.every(function (key) { 
      return down[key]; 
    });
    if (allPressed) {
      funcName.apply(this, args);
    }
    down[e.keyCode] = false;
  });
}
```

That gets any number of keys passed into the function by treating the `arguments` like an array. Then the `keyup` handler uses the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method of `Array` to make sure all of the entries in the array have been pressed.

I should warn you I haven't tested this in a working application, since none was provided, but I'm pretty sure it will function as a replacement.

If you want help with sorting out this string you talk about in the question, do include it in the question, or add a new question specifically about that code.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. I didn't know I could create an array of the arguments so easily. Thanks!